# Delphi XE7 AcroPDF (Acrobat Reader PDF ActiveX) component steals focus

Tags: delphi, pdf, acrobat, delphi-xe7

When I open a pdf document using the AcroPDF component, AcroPDF steals the focus of my edit component (edSuchName)... 
the only way that I found to get it back is the following, but I'm not really glad with it. So I'm searching for something better

```
    TMainForm = class(TForm)
      AcroPDF1: TAcroPDF;
      tmrBringFocusBack: TTimer;
      edSearchName: TEdit;
      procedure tmrBringFocusBackTimer(Sender: TObject);
      procedure OpenDocument;
    end;
 // ...
    procedure TMainform.tmrBringFocusBackTimer(Sender: TObject);
    begin
      tmrBringFocusBack.Enabled := False;
      edSearchName.SetFocus;
    end;

    procedure TMainform.OpenDocument;
    begin
      AcroPDF1.LoadFile(AFilename);
      AcroPDF1.setShowToolbar(false);
      AcroPDF1.setPageMode('none');
      AcroPDF1.Show;
      tmrBringFocusBack.Interval:= 200; // and sometimes more (when trying, 20 is too less)

      tmrBringFocusBack.Enabled := True; // <<<< I have to trigger this timer <<<<
    end;
```

Does anybody know a better way?

Comment: This component is just about the worst component around. It's going to make you feel dirty.

Comment: Aren't there events in the component you can use such as OnShow ?  Maybe you can subclass it and add an event you can use.  I wont be close to a proper PC to investigate this properly, for several weeks.